# ERR_PNPM_PEER_DEP_ISSUES Unmet peer dependencies github action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, github, github-actions, pnpm

## Environment

- React
- Typescript
- Emotion
- PNPM Monorepo

## Github Action

```
name: cart npm publish

on:
  release:
    types: [published]
  workflow_dispatch:

defaults:
  run:
    working-directory: packages/cart

jobs:
  publish-npm:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: pnpm/action-setup@v2
        with:
          version: 7.10.0
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'
          registry-url: 'https://registry.npmjs.org'

      - name: Dependency install
        run: pnpm install

      - name: Compile
        run: pnpm build

      - name: Publish
        run: npm publish --access public

        env:
          NODE_AUTH_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.NPM_TOKEN }}
```

## Error Content

```
 ERR_PNPM_PEER_DEP_ISSUES  Unmet peer dependencies

packages/configs/eslint-ts-react
├─┬ @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin 5.62.0
│ ├── ✕ missing peer typescript@"*"
│ └─┬ @typescript-eslint/type-utils 5.62.0
│   ├── ✕ missing peer typescript@"*"
│   └─┬ @typescript-eslint/typescript-estree 5.62.0
│     ├── ✕ missing peer typescript@"*"
│     └─┬ tsutils 3.21.0
│       └── ✕ missing peer typescript@">=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta"
└─┬ @typescript-eslint/parser 5.62.0
  └── ✕ missing peer typescript@"*"
Peer dependencies that should be installed:
  typescript@>=2.8.0

packages/payment
└─┬ styled-components 5.3.11
  └─┬ babel-plugin-styled-components 2.1.4
    └─┬ @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx 7.22.5
      └── ✕ missing peer @babel/core@^7.0.0-0
Peer dependencies that should be installed:
  @babel/core@^7.0.0-0

hint: If you want peer dependencies to be automatically installed, add "auto-install-peers=true" to an .npmrc file at the root of your project.
hint: If you don't want pnpm to fail on peer dependency issues, add "strict-peer-dependencies=false" to an .npmrc file at the root of your project.

Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

## .npmrc

```
engine-strict=true
auto-install-peers=true
strict-peer-dependencies=false
```

How to solve this problem ?